# Run webservice-app on embedded Tomcat server or real webserver?

Tags: java, spring, apache, web-services, tomcat

I have a WAR web application that I'm running using `spring-boot` during dev with an *embedded*  `tomcat8` server.

I'm tending to run the tomcat in production behind a `httpd` apache proxy anyways. The proxy will handle any communication to the outside, including https/ssl handling. And forward the requests just to `/localhost:8080/myapp`. So the tomcat (if embedded or not) is not exposed, but only the path within http.

The only reason I need a `tomcat` is that I'm exposing an API `XML` webservice in my app.

**Question: Are there major advantages of a *real* tomcat webserver over an *embedded* tomcat?** Does a normal webserver provide features an embedded does not? Eg is a real tomcat better reagarding performance, session handling, or can accept more requests concurrently?

I can think of the following advantages of an embedded server, but maybe there are cons I'm not seeing right now?

- Shutdown and restart each WAR app individually (in a real tomcat webserver, I could of course undeploy/delete the apps in `/webapp` folder. But if I restart the server, all apps are down)
- Better independance of the apps. Eg if one app crashes for whatever reason with a Memory/Heapspace overflow, this will kill only that single app. (in a tomcat webserver, this might kill the whole webserver and thus all applications)
- simplicy of moving to another server: I can just create a fat jar (with `spring-boot`) and run it simply by command line. Add java memory and custom parameters there. Finished.
  In a tomcat webserver, I'd have to touch multiple files for those configurations.

Unsure about: would an embedded tomcat also support reqquest/response compression?

Comment: Almost all that you are able to do with Standalone Tomcat, you can do with an embedded one. And the current trend is for the embedded one. If you look at other language stacks and microservices and 12-factor apps, most of them are running on embedded servers. So I would say you would be fine with the embedded one.

Comment: You should probably rephrase your question so that it doesn't ask for opinions but rather asks for some clarifications/explanations (i.e., the middle part of your question probably doesn't need to be there). Opinion-driven questions tend to receive opposite answers depending on what is a current "hot" thing is, which is hardly helpful for future readers.

Comment: Well but the initial question remains: are there any advantages of a normal tomcat server over an embedded webserver? But to some degree, answers to that question will always be based on the current "trend". Eg 5 years ago you'd probably answered: "only use a real tomcat webserver". Whereas nowadays the answer might be "use embedded", because it makes sense today, and embedded servers have evolved in a good direction. Anyways again in 5 years the view may have shifted. One could probably not generalize answers here.